# Jest unit test - How do i simulate a click event for table row icon

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

How will I write jest/enzyme unit test to simulate a click handler for a **row icon** that will display only on hover over [or] click on the table row.

```
**code that I tried given below:-**

let wrapper = mount(<TableComponent {...mockData} />);
 wrapper.find('.table-row').simulate('click');
```

`wrapper.find('.row-action-icon').simulate('click')` // failing as row-action-icon is not attached to the DOM

Can someone help me on fixing this issue?

Comment: You need attach Table component code. it's hard to see any problems right now)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the solution for the above scenario. It might help someone

```
   1) Mocking the component using jest mount.
   const wrapper = mount(<TableComponent {...mockData} />);

    2) Trigger a mounse enter for the table row.
    wrapper.find('.table__body__row').at(0).props().onMouseEnter();

    3) Update the wrapper. It will intern update the DOM and insert the row icon.
    wrapper.update();
   
    4) Finally we can perform the action for the row icon
    wrapper.find('.row-actions-menu__trigger').simulate('click');
```

- Similarly, we can use "@testing-library/react";

  ```
   const { container } = render(<TableComponent {...mockTableData} />);
   fireEvent.mouseOver(container.querySelector(".table__body__row"));

   const menuIcon = container.querySelector(".row-actions-menu__trigger");
   fireEvent.click(menuIcon);
   expect(menuIcon).not.toBeNull();
  ```